# Advice requested for navigating in large applications

Tags: c#, user-controls, navigation, panel

I want to create an application that has different views. I put my different components in different panels. By clicking on a button, I would like to see the panel that belongs to that button. Is there any other way to navigate between panels besides setting the visibility to false?

Or is there a better way to navigate using other components other than panel?

Comment: Winforms?  Webforms?  Silverlight?  Wpf?  Mvc?

Comment: In addition to Eric J, this really depends on the user experience you're looking for and what you're trying to achieve on your UI. It's like saying "how should I build my car engine", when we don't know what sort of performance you're looking for.

Comment: What i actually want to achieve is lets say a large application to fill in application form on my first page i would like to have something like "personal detials" then a button to take u to the next part of the application by going to total new layout

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx).

This allows you to add several TabPages and switch between them by clicking on the tab you want to see.

---

**Update**

From your comment it seems you are looking to create a *wizard*. If so, see these related questions:

- [What is the best way to create a wizard in C# 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-wizard-in-c-sharp-2-0)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195255/best-wizard-control-for-net-windows-forms
- [Creating Wizards for Windows Forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340566/creating-wizards-for-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)
- [Good patterns for building a wizard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480547/good-patterns-for-building-a-wizard)
- etc....

Comment: Not tabcontrol some cleaner like when u have a button to go next page and it takes u to something different

Answer (score 0):

What about displaying only one panel on the main form:

```
this.Controls.Clear();
this.Controls.Add(this.panel1); //panel2, panel3, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to not initialize them all at once: it takes time to build controls and consumes a lot of memory.

Create the panel with controls when requested. Then act as anth suggested.